# Superfish Function Error

Tags: jquery, superfish

When I view my page with Firebug I get the following error message:

> jQuery("ul.nav").superfish is not a function

I have it targeting my class of `nav`. I can supply more code if needed but I was wondering if there is something I am missing which would be causing this error. TIA.

Comment: <script src="js/libs/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

I am currently using that in my head at the moment

Comment: Actually what I meant to say was reference your jquery before you superfish, sorry. So switch those script tags around.

Comment: I had it setup like that before, jquery before superfish which is where I get that error from.

Comment: jQuery 1.2 is ANCIENT. You should switch to 1.6.4!

Comment: Are you sure both files exist?

Comment: I was only using it has a test to see if it was jQuery causing the issue being the latest version (out there I know) but I have switched it back to 1.6.4.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Yes both files exist are are referenced correctly.

Comment: Edit the files, add `alert("jQuery file");` and `alert("superfish file");` - do you see both alerts? The thing is, you have no indication when the files are not really loaded.

Comment: I added in those lines and the jQuery box comes up first followed superfish, it appears to be loading correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Superfish is a jQuery plugin. You must always include the jQuery library before the plugin because the plugin depends on the jQuery library.